# Windows driver only save binary file

Tags: c#, c++, windows, printing

I need own printer on Windows. I just need when I from any application (adobe reader, IE etc.) have open html page, or PDF when I click on file, print choose printer and this printer only take original input data as binary and just save to file disk.

I try to solve this problem with `universla PS` drivers for windows, but convert file from ps back to `PDF` or `XPS` can destroy `PDF`. Do you know some drivers or example?

Windows printer drivers according to documentation on `MSDN` can be only in C++. So I like avoid to write driver by own. I have my own port which can take document from printer and save them. But I still need driver which just take input after `Ctrl+P` arise and send to my port or save to disk.

Comment: You can't save the application-specific data by printing. You can only save that from the application, only the application knows what data it should save, and in what format. When you choose 'print' you actually direct the application to 'draw' the content (ie what you would see on screen) to the printer device, which converts that into the pritner language.

Comment: Thanks for yors reply. I think so too but still i hope, that could be way to just take data from application and save. We will see. maybe somebody has higher experience.